# Can someone point out to me why this code is not working

Tags: android

```
   public boolean checkFormat(String username){

         ArrayList<Character> charList = new ArrayList<Character>();
        Collections.addAll(charList, '!', '$', '#', '@');

    //Check for special Character
    boolean containsSpecial = false;
    for(Character character: charList) {
        if (username.contains(Character.toString(character))) {
            containsSpecial = true;
        }
    }
    //Check for Letters
    int numberCharacters = 0;
    if(containsSpecial){
        for(int i=0; i<username.length();i++){
            String symbol = String.valueOf(username.charAt(i));

            //REGEX pattern Check
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-z]");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(symbol);

            if(matcher.matches()){
                numberCharacters++;
                System.out.println("Match: " + numberCharacters);
            }
        }
    }

    if(numberCharacters>2){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

What does this block of code mean? It says username should be at least 3 characters right? because whenever i enter janice as username i get the error username is not in correct format

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I think it is trying to check that the `username` contains a special character AND at least 3 letters.  Except that the letter test looks messed up.  (Hint: read the regex carefully ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input `"janice"` returns `false` because when the input contains no special characters, the counting loop isn't executed at all and `numberCharacters` remains set to 0.

The code you've posted is horribly inefficient for what it's supposed to do. You might try something like this instead:

```
public boolean checkFormat(String username){
    final int len = username.length();
    int charCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        final char c = Character.toLowerCase(username.charAt(i));
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
            charCount++;
        }
    }
    return charCount > 2;
}
```

There are other ways to do this, of course. This is just one possible approach.

It's not clear what role you envision for the special characters, but if you just want to check for the presence of at least one special character, you can modify the above as follows:

```
private static final Pattern SPECIALS = Pattern.compile("[!$#@]");

public boolean checkFormat(String username) {
    if (!SPECIALS.matcher(username).find()) {
        return false;
    }
    ... // the logic as before
}
```

Of course, reverse the sense of the `if` test if your goal is to reject strings containing any of those special characters.

As an aside: if you want to use regular expressions, you should be aware that the regex `[A-z]` represents a character class that contains a number of special characters. (Consult an ASCII or Unicode code chart to see which ones.) If you want to test for alphabetic characters, use `[A-Za-z]` or just `[a-z]` and convert the input string to lower case or set the case-insensitive flag for the pattern.